# C# Graphics class: get size of drawn content

Tags: c#, image, graphics, drawing, bitmap

I am writing to a Graphics object dynamically and don't know the actual size of the final image until all output is passed.

So, I create a large image and create Graphics object from it:

```
int iWidth = 600;
int iHeight = 2000;

bmpImage = new Bitmap(iWidth, iHeight);            
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
```

How can I find the actual size of written content, so I will be able to create a new bitmap with this size and copy the content to it.

It is really hard to calculate the content size before drawing it and want to know if there is any other solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You create a new, empty bitmap of a particular size.  You get a graphical surface from that bitmap. You then fill that graphical surface with the color white.  There is nothing here that would indicate a size change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is probably to keep track of the maximum X and Y values that get used as you draw, though this will be an entirely manual process.

Another option would be to scan full rows and columns of the bitmap (starting from the right and the bottom) until you encounter a non-white pixel, but this will be a very inefficient process.

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

for(int x = bmpImage.Width - 1, x >= 0, x++)
{
    bool foundNonWhite = false;

    width = x + 1;

    for(int y = 0; y < bmpImage.Height; y++)
    {
        if(bmpImage.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.White)
        {
            foundNonWhite = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(foundNonWhite) break;
}

for(int y = bmpImage.Height - 1, x >= 0, x++)
{
    bool foundNonWhite = false;

    height = y + 1;

    for(int x = 0; x < bmpImage.Width; x++)
    {
        if(bmpImage.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.White)
        {
            foundNonWhite = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(foundNonWhite) break;
}
```

Again, **I don't recommend this as a solution**, but it *will* do what you want without your having to keep track of the coordinate space that you actually use.

Comment: Thanks! Keep tracking of the maximum X and Y values that get used as draw will work for me.

Comment: I'm assuming that clipping off of the left or the top isn't going to happen?

Comment: @Jacob: That was my assumption, but either pattern could be fairly easily adapted to account for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Just check the value of these properties**

```
float width = graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
float height = graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height;
```

> [A RectangleF structure that represents a bounding rectangle for the visible clipping region of this Graphics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.visibleclipbounds)